# Splitting results by decades in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables (simplified) in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE party(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    family_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE election(
    id int,
    country_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    e_type election_type NOT NULL,
    e_date date NOT NULL,
    vote_share numeric,
    seats int,
    seats_total int NOT NULL,
    party_name_short varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    party_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_name_english varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    party_id int REFERENCES party(id)
);
```

I like to know how a certain political party family (Conservatives, Social Democracy and so on) in elections. It can be done quite easily:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM e.e_date) AS year,
    sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share
FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    e.e_date
```

I'd like to know how certain party family performs in elections by decades, ie. what is vote share in years 1980-1989, 1990-1999 and son on. Luckily, `Postgres` has `date_trunc` function which does exactly what I want. I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share,
    extract(year FROM date_trunc('decade', e.e_date)) || 's' AS decade
    FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    decade
```

It does incorrect results as it seems to simply sum vote share. The query should instead sum the vote share in each election in a given decade and then divide by the number of election in that decade. How do I do that?

Here's my incorrect results:

```
|country_name|vote_share|decade|
|------------|----------|------|
|Austria     |8.2       |1980s |
|Austria     |26.3      |1990s |
|Austria     |31        |2000s |
|Austria     |36.4      |2010s |
--------------------------------
```

As per comment, I provide input data:

```
+---------+------+------------+
| country | year | vote_share |
+---------+------+------------+
| Austria | 1983 |        1.4 |
| Austria | 1983 |        2.0 |
| Austria | 1986 |        4.8 |
| Austria | 1990 |        4.8 |
| Austria | 1990 |        2.0 |
| Austria | 1994 |        7.3 |
| Austria | 1995 |        4.8 |
| Austria | 1999 |        7.4 |
+---------+------+------------+
```

Expected result:

```
1980s: sum: 1,4 + 2 + 4,8 = 8,2
average vote share: 8,2 / 2 = 4,1 --  here I divide by 2 because there were two elections (1983, 1986)
```

Comment: `sum(e.vote_share) AS vote_share/10`? To get a complete answer you will need to  provide some input data as well as expected output. Add as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I updated my post. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: If there where only two elections in the 80's how come there are three entries?

Comment: Because there are two parties of profile Green `AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The query should instead sum the vote share in each election in a given decade and then divide by the number of election in that decade.

There's nothing stopping you from doing arithmetics with [aggregate expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) exactly how you phrased it:

```sql
sum(e.vote_share) --'sum the vote share in each election in a given decade'
  /                                 --'and then divide'
count(distinct                      --'by the number'
      extract(year FROM e.e_date) ) --'of elections in that decade'
```

The second function counts different election years that, by nature, are unique within the decade you're already grouping by, effectively giving you the number of elections in that decade. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/deWsbz6h):

```sql
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    extract(year FROM date_trunc('decade', e.e_date)) || 's' AS decade,
    sum(e.vote_share)/count(distinct extract(year FROM e.e_date)) AS vote_share
FROM election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    decade
```

| country_name | decade | vote_share |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 1980s | 4.1000000000000000 |
| Austria | 1990s | 6.5750000000000000 |

Apart from adding that one division you wanted, your query can remain unchanged.

Comment: What a clear solution! Perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the sum of votes by the vote count per decade.

This below should help:

```
   with cte as
(
    Select count(*) as elect_count, extract(year FROM date_trunc('decade', e_date)) || 's' AS decade
    From election
    group by decade
),
cte2 as
(
SELECT
    e.country_name,
    sum(e.vote_share) vote_share,
    extract(year FROM date_trunc('decade', e.e_date)) || 's' AS decade
    FROM
    election e
    JOIN party p ON e.party_id = p.id
 
WHERE
    e.e_type = 'parliament'
    AND p.family_name IN ('Green/Ecologist')
    AND e.country_name = 'Austria'
    AND e.e_date >= '1980-01-01'::date
    AND e.e_date < '2020-01-01'::date
GROUP BY
    e.country_name,
    decade
  )
  select country_name, vote_share/elect_count, vote_share, elect_count, a.decade
  From cte2 a left join cte b on a.decade = b.decade
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this query has some errors - I cannot execute it.

Comment: Now it looks promising, however, I get very small numbers from `vote_share/elect_count`, e.g. `0.00928652321630804077`.